# json bad format use board Ruby

Tags: json, ruby

I've a problem with  json format, when I want to use it with a board.
In my json file each information have separate with double brackets while i should have only bracket, is it possible to delete one of them?

code :

```
elsif (params[:which] == "BigSize")
  res= []
  #   PrintType.where("width > 70").where("width <= 120").where("height > 118.9").where("height <= 150").pluck('DISTINCT artwork_id')
  big = PrintType.where("width > 70").where("width <= 120").where("height > 118.9").where("height <= 150").pluck('DISTINCT artwork_id')
  res << [big]
  render :json => res.to_json(include: { :images => { :except => :img_orig } })
```

result : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u44T.png)

Comment: Do Not use photo as result.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing an array into an array `res << [big]`
To stop creating two brackets just write `res << big` or if it is necesarry for another reason flatten the `res` before you convert it to json

Comment: Thanks for your help ! , I've just a last question , why have I again 2 brackets at the beginning of the file and at the end ?

Comment: Do you have the two brackets still although you did one of my suggestion up there?

Comment: Any news here? Do you still have the problem?